# Inner class is null when converting json to C# objects

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to convert a string containing Json (pinterest) to c# objects.  I am using Json .NET and no matter what I try, the data.pins.images inner text is always converted to null.  It clearly is not null.

The c# classes were created by an online converter.  The actual Json's 'pins' array contained 50 elements.  I stripped all but one of them out in order to simplify the problem.

The Json text and test program is listed below.  Please help.

```
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
//using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

namespace PinterestConsoleTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string jsonString = 
            "{"+
                "\"status\": \"success\","+
                "\"code\": 0,"+
                "\"host\": \"ngapi2-67c11435\","+
                "\"generated_at\": \"Sun, 07 Dec 2014 12:15:10 +0000\","+
                "\"message\": \"ok\","+
                "\"data\": "+
                "{"+
                    "\"pins\": "+
                    "["+
                        "{"+
                            "\"attribution\": null,"+
                            "\"description\": \"Roasted Potato Salad with Pancetta, Sun-Dried Tomatoes and Arugula\","+
                            "\"pinner\": "+
                            "{"+
                                "\"about\": \"\","+
                                "\"location\": \"\","+
                                "\"full_name\": \"Anselma Berumen\","+
                                "\"follower_count\": 15,"+
                                "\"image_small_url\": \"http://passets-ak.pinterest.com/images/user/default_30.png\","+
                                "\"pin_count\": 1683,"+
                                "\"id\": \"460422899312895060\","+
                                "\"profile_url\": \"http://www.pinterest.com/chemita1331/\""+
                            "},"+
                            "\"repin_count\": 0,"+
                            "\"dominant_color\": \"#b7947a\","+
                            "\"like_count\": 0,"+
                            "\"link\": \"http://www.domesticate-me.com/roasted-potato-salad-with-pancetta-sun-dried-tomatoes-and-arugula/\","+
                            "\"images\": "+
                            "{"+
                                "\"image\": "+
                                "{"+
                                    "\"url\": \"http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/237x/a0/97/9e/a0979eb898eee640eb980181035e75bc.jpg\","+
                                    "\"width\": 237,"+
                                    "\"height\": 334"+
                                "}" +
                            "},"+
                            "\"embed\": null,"+
                            "\"is_video\": false,"+
                            "\"id\": \"460422761878479851\""+
                        "}"+
                    "],"+
                    "\"user\": "+
                    "{"+
                        "\"about\": \"\","+
                        "\"location\": \"\","+
                        "\"full_name\": \"Anselma Berumen\","+
                        "\"follower_count\": 15,"+
                        "\"image_small_url\": \"http://passets-ak.pinterest.com/images/user/default_30.png\","+
                        "\"pin_count\": 1683,"+
                        "\"id\": \"460422899312895060\","+
                        "\"profile_url\": \"http://www.pinterest.com/chemita1331/\""+
                    "},"+
                    "\"board\": "+
                    "{"+
                        "\"description\": \"\","+
                        "\"url\": \"/chemita1331/salads/\","+
                        "\"follower_count\": 4,"+
                        "\"image_thumbnail_url\": \"http://media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/upload/460422830593447062_board_thumbnail_2014-09-18-00-49-37_15359_60.jpg\","+
                        "\"pin_count\": 237,"+
                        "\"id\": \"460422830593447062\","+
                        "\"name\": \"Salads\""+
                    "}"+
                "}"+
            "}";

            JsonPinterestTester jsonPinterestTester = new JsonPinterestTester();

            PinsOfBoardRequest pinsOfBoardRequest = jsonPinterestTester.Parse(jsonString);

            PinsOfBoardRequestImages images =   pinsOfBoardRequest.data.pins[0].images;

            Image237x image = pinsOfBoardRequest.data.pins[0].images.image237x;

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class JsonPinterestTester
    {
        public PinsOfBoardRequest Parse(string jsonSource)
        {
            PinsOfBoardRequest request = 
                Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PinsOfBoardRequest>(jsonSource);
            return request;
        }
    }

    public class Image237x
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public int width { get; set; }
        public int height { get; set; }
    }

    public class PinsOfBoardRequestImages
    {
        public Image237x image237x { get; set; }
    }

    public class PinsOfBoardRequestPinner
    {
        public string about { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }
        public string full_name { get; set; }
        public int follower_count { get; set; }
        public string image_small_url { get; set; }
        public int pin_count { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string profile_url { get; set; }
    }

    public class PinsOfBoardRequestUser
    {
        public string about { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }
        public string full_name { get; set; }
        public int follower_count { get; set; }
        public string image_small_url { get; set; }
        public int pin_count { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string profile_url { get; set; }
    }

    public class PinsOfBoardRequestBoard
    {
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public int follower_count { get; set; }
        public string image_thumbnail_url { get; set; }
        public int pin_count { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class PinsOfBoardRequestPin
    {
        public object attribution { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public PinsOfBoardRequestPinner pinner { get; set; }
        public int repin_count { get; set; }
        public string dominant_color { get; set; }
        public int like_count { get; set; }
        public string link { get; set; }
        public PinsOfBoardRequestImages images { get; set; }
        public object embed { get; set; }
        public bool is_video { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class PinsOfBoardRequestData
    {
        //public IList<PinsOfBoardRequestPin> pins { get; set; }
        public PinsOfBoardRequestPin[] pins { get; set; }
        public PinsOfBoardRequestUser user { get; set; }
        public PinsOfBoardRequestBoard board { get; set; }
    }

    public class PinsOfBoardRequest
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public int code { get; set; }
        public string host { get; set; }
        public string generated_at { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public PinsOfBoardRequestData data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely, the `Image237x` property of `PinsOfBoardRequestImages` class should be named `image`

```
public class PinsOfBoardRequestImages
{
    public Image237x image { get; set; }
}
```

Also, given the name `images` which would potentially infer an array, double check that your sample matches the actual input

Is it really:

```
images: { image: { ..
```

Or is it:

```
images:  [{ image: {.. , image { ...] ?
```

In which case the DTO would be an array:

```
    public Image237x[] image { get; set; }
```

Comment: Yes it should.  Thanks, Stuart, and don't call me Shirley.

Comment: I am having trouble figuring how to fully respond to your helpful comment.  My problem began with the fact that in the Json that is returned from the server, the 'image' label above is actually '237x'.  So I had to change the resultant class and property names.  But based on what I just learned from you, I can't change the property names.  How can I get around the '237x' problem?

Comment: Found it.  [JsonProperty("237x")]  Thanks.